# Automate concatenate formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to automate a concatenate and if formula with VBA.

The formula.

```
=concatenate(if(Isblank(w2),””,W2&Char(10)),if(Isblank(x2),””,x2&Char(10)), if(Isblank(y2),””,Y2&Char(10)), if(Isblank(z2),””,z2&Char(10))
```

I tried this code.

```vb
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1

Dim lrow
Lrow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Count

ws.range(“$W$2:$Z” & lrow) = concatenate(if(Isblank(w2),””,W2&Char(10)),if(Isblank(x2),””,x2&Char(10)), if(Isblank(y2),””,Y2&Char(10)), if(Isblank(z2),””,z2&Char(10))
```

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,W2:Z2)`

Comment: @P.b why make things difficult if they can be so simple, great answer!

Comment: @mtholen agreed but it also depends on the version of Excel on whether the OP can achieve that or not.

Answer (score 0):

### Concat Columns

```vb
Sub ConcatColumns()

    Dim Formula As String: Formula = "=Concatenate(" _
        & "IF(ISBLANK(W2),"""",W2&Char(10))," _
        & "IF(ISBLANK(X2),"""",X2&Char(10))," _
        & "IF(ISBLANK(Y2),"""",Y2&Char(10))," _
        & "IF(ISBLANK(Z2),"""",Z2&Char(10)))"
    ' To write '""' to a formula, you need to use '""""'.
    ' To write '"' to a formula, you need to use '"""'.
    ' To not have the empty row at the bottom of each cell,
    ' remove the last '&CHAR(10)'.
    ' When you have such a long formula, it is always better to write
    ' it to a variable so you can test it with e.g.
    Debug.Print Formula
    ' until you get it right.

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.UsedRange.Count
    
    ' You need to write to a different column than the columns in the formula.
    With ws.Range("V2", ws.Cells(lRow, "V"))
        .Formula = Formula
        ' To utilize the new line character, in Excel, you have to enable
        ' 'Format Cells->Alignment->Wrap Text' or in VBA, use:
        .WrapText = True
        ' If you want to remove the formulae, you can do the following:
        '.Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```